# Wix - Only Install Package via Custom Action when a specific registry doesnt exist

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, wix3

I have tried for 10 hours million things but I don't get it to work. Here is my code (extract):

```
<Fragment>
    <util:RegistrySearch Id="VC_REDIST_Version"
      Root="HKCR"
      Variable="VCREDIST143431931"
      Key="Installer\Dependencies\VC,redist.x86,x86,14.34,bundle"
      Format="raw" 
      Value="Version"
      Result="value" />    

    <ComponentGroup Id="ThirdPartyComponents" Directory="ExtSources">
      <Component Id="Component_VC_redist_x86" Guid="2B80F89A-990A-438E-A475-9E72d8A0198A" >
        <File Id="ExtSources_VC_redist.x86.exe" Name="VC_redist.x86.exe" Source="$(var.xxxxx_TargetDir)ExtSources\VC_redist.x86.exe" />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>

    <CustomAction Id="Install_VC_redist_x86"
      Execute="immediate"
      Impersonate="no"
      Return="asyncNoWait"
      FileKey="ExtSources_VC_redist.x86.exe"
      ExeCommand="" />

      <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="Install_VC_redist_x86" After="InstallFinalize">NOT VCREDIST143431931</Custom>
      </InstallExecuteSequence>

  </Fragment>
```

But the problem is that the Custom action is executed always, independent from the state.

Any Idea what might be wrong?

**UPDATE:**

This is now how I did it and it works including skipping calling the installer when there is already a newer or same version of vc distrib installed:

```
  <Fragment>
    
    <Property Id="VCREDISTINSTALLED">
      <RegistrySearch Id="VCRedistInstalledSearch"
                      Root="HKCR"
                      Key="Installer\Dependencies\VC,redist.x86,x86,14.34,bundle"
                      Name="Version"
                      Type="raw" 
                      Win64="no"/>
    </Property>

    <ComponentGroup Id="ThirdPartyComponents" Directory="ExtSources">
      <Component Id="Component_VC_redist_x86" Guid="2B80F89A-990A-438E-A475-9E72d8A0198A" >
        <File Id="ExtSources_VC_redist.x86.exe" Name="VC_redist.x86.exe" Source="$(var.xxxxx_TargetDir)ExtSources\VC_redist.x86.exe" />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>

    <CustomAction Id="Install_VC_redist_x86"
      Execute="immediate"
      Return="asyncNoWait"
      FileKey="ExtSources_VC_redist.x86.exe"
      ExeCommand="/quiet /norestart" />

      <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="Install_VC_redist_x86" After="InstallFinalize"><![CDATA[VCREDISTINSTALLED < "14.34.31931.0" AND NOT REMOVE]]></Custom>
      </InstallExecuteSequence>

  </Fragment>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `RegistrySearch` instead of `util:RegistrySearch`. The `util:RegistrySearch` is only recognized in Bundles. In WiX v4, there is a error message but in WiX v3 it is silently ignored.

Comment: Thank you. I have tested this before but it was not working, this is why I have switched to util, but now i am back to RegistrySearch again and it works. I will post my working example right now